# Absolute maximum on $(-\infty, \infty)$, must be local maximum?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I think yes, and I think it must true for any open interval not just $(-\infty, \infty)$

Just wanted confirmation, OR am I wrong

Comment: Yes. Every absolute maximum is also a local maximum.

Comment: Every absolute maximum is a local maximum but not the converse...

Answer (score 2):

Let $M\in\mathbb{R}$ be an absolute maximum on $(-\infty,\infty)$ for a function $f$ defined in $\mathbb{R}$.

Then $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\,f(x)\le M$.

Let $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $\varepsilon>0$.

$\forall x\in ]x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon[,\,x\in\mathbb{R}$ and so $\forall x\in ]x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon[,\,f(x)\le M$ thus $M$ is a local maximum at any point of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @stoic: To push this to a generic open interval, you can simply choose $\varepsilon$ to be small enough that $(x_0-\varepsilon, x_0+\varepsilon)\in (a,b)$. This explains why you cannot use the same trick if you have an endpoint; if the maximum is at the endpoint then no such $\varepsilon>0$ exists.